# android animations problem with language

Tags: android, animation

hi
i want to appy animation between activities,
for that i have written following sentence.
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_enter);
it works fine.
but when i change the device language to dutch it generates error.
so what is problem in this i can not determined it.
please help me 
thanx in advance

Comment: 03-30 19:45:41.078: ERROR/dalvikvm(364): Could not find method Dignizant.Gravid.view.overridePendingTransition, referenced from method Dignizant.Gravid.view$1.onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add animation between Activities it is better to do in next way:

1) create values\styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Animation" />
 <style name="Animation.MyAwesomeAnimation">
  <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/myawesomeanimation_enter</item>
  <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/hold_long</item>
  <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/hold_long</item>
  <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/myawesomeanimation_exit</item>
```

Animations should be placed into anim folder, of course.

2) create values\themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAwesomeTheme" parent="Theme.Default">     
 <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.MyAwesomeAnimation</item>       
</style>
```

3) set in AndroidManifest.xml this theme for your Actibity:

```
<activity
 android:name=".MyAwesomeActivity"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAwesomeTheme" />
```

This works fine for me. overridePendingTransition() method works only since API level 5 and may cause problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add try/catch block to your sentence, then toggle breakpoint to exception. Try debug your program again. From the exception, you could know reason why it generates error.

Hopefully can help you.